# PayFast payment integration in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to integrate PayFast payments in ReactJS.

As per [the documentation](https://developers.payfast.co.za/documentation/#getting-started) by PayFast, when the form is submitted as a POST request, the user is directed to the PayFast payments page.

How will I know, when the payment is completed or cancelled from the notify_url?

PayFast only shows PHP examples. Can I also handle this through NodeJS?

Comment: PayFast will send a post back to your notify_url, before the user is redirected back to your return_url, when a payment is completed. If a payment is cancelled the user will be returned to your cancel_url. It is important to note that no payment data ever gets posted to the return_url or cancel_url. https://developers.payfast.co.za/documentation/#notify-page-itn

Comment: Thank you @Daniel_ZA. What about cancelation of subscription do you have reference which help to cancel subscription. I contact support team they told me currently payfast doesn't support JavaScript but it's not like that I successfully completed the add hic and get subscription using JavaScript now working on cancellation of subscription.

Comment: what they mean by "not supporting javascript" is that you cannot use JS to post directly to the API endpoint due to CORS (this a different endpoint to the one used for creating a subscription). You will need to perform any subsequent API calls (update, charge, pause, cancel) from a server side script (PHP, node, etc) after the subscription has been created.

Comment: @Daniel_ZA Thanx after some more try I achieve the task.
Thank You.

Comment: @jatin.7744 how did you implemented it. I am also working on payfast with vuejs and laravel but I am not able to do this. can you please share demo code or any working example. Thanks

Comment: @NikulKhatik Let me know any issue you face I put a sample code as an answer of my question itself.

Comment: Thanks @jatin.7744 but I have found a solution and its workig now

Answer (score 3):

I successfully implement it in ReactJS, Hope it will help you.
What I did at the front I make an object of required informations.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams({
  merchant_id: "....",
  merchant_key: "....",
  return_url: "https://yourApplication/paymentscreen",
  cancel_url: "https://yourApplication/paymentscreen",
  notify_url: "https://yourApplication/paymentscreen",
  name_first: name,
  email_address: email,
  m_payment_id: unique_id_for_user,
  amount: amount,
  item_name: payment_name,
  item_description: description_if_any,
  custom_int1: custome_integer_value_if_any,
  custom_str1: custome_string_value_if_any,
  custom_str2: custome_string_value_if_any,
  passphrase: passphrase_set_in_payfast_account.
});

// Create an MD5 signature of it.
const MD5Signature = md5(params.toString())
```

Now what I did submit a hidden form on click of payment button.
Make sure the sequence is important here they did mention any information regarding the sequence of fields I also face many issues but later after too much debugging I got the right sequence.

```
<form action="https://www.payfast.co.za/eng/process" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="...." />
          <input type="hidden" name="merchant_key" value="....." />
          <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="https://yourApplication/paymentscreen" />
          <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="https://yourApplication/paymentscreen" />
          <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://yourApplication/paymentscreen" />
          <input type="hidden" name="name_first" value={name} />
          <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value={email} />
          <input type="hidden" name="m_payment_id" value={unique_id_for_user} />
          <input type="hidden" name="amount" value={amount} />
          <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value={payment_name} />
          <input type="hidden" name="item_description" value={description_if_any} />
          <input type="hidden" name="custom_int1" value={custome_integer_value_if_any} />
          <input type="hidden" name="custom_str1" value={custome_string_value_if_any} />
          <input type="hidden" name="custom_str2" value={custome_string_value_if_any} />
          <input type="hidden" name="passphrase" value="passphrase" />
          <input type="hidden" name="signature" value={MD5Signature} />
          <div className="row" style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <div className="col-lg-6">
              <img alt="payfast" src="../public/upload/payfastpaynow.png" vspace="3" width="100%" height="100%" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-6">
                <input style={{marginRight: 20, float: 'right'}} name="disable" type="submit" disabled={isEnablePayment} width="100%" height="100%" alt="Submit" align="bottom" value="Purchase" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```